# Hiding param value in URL - JSF Application

Tags: jsf

```
<h:outputLink value="#{beanname.path}">
    <h:outputText value="Output label"></h:outputText>
    <f:param name name="name" value="tommy"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

http://127.0.0.1:7101/projectt/faces/index.jsp?name=tommy
my URL appears with the param value. I want to hide it in the URL and get it in the bean class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want a POST request? Use `<h:commandLink>` instead.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Output label" action="#{beanname.outcome}">
        <f:param name name="name" value="tommy"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

The parameter can be set as

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.name}")
private String name;
```

or can passed by `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instead:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Output label" action="#{beanname.outcome}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{beanname.name}" value="tommy"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

or when you're already on a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), just pass it as action method argument:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Output label" action="#{beanname.outcome('tommy')}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public String outcome(String name) {
    // ...

    return "index";
}
```